# Unlink jpeg file when the url path is provided by a value of the mysql database

Tags: php, delete-file, unlink

I'm trying to delete a jpg. The path to that image is stored in the database under the field name PandFoto3. After that I empty the field in the database. So far I have the following code:

```
    if(isset($_POST['F3Verwijderen']))
    try 
    {               
        
        //delete the file
        $sql = "SELECT PandFoto3 FROM tblpand WHERE `PK_Pand` = '".$pandid."'";
        
        $con = mysql_connect('immocorbati.be.mysql', 'immocorbati_be', 'zx4ge6ty');
        if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        mysql_select_db("immocorbati_be");
        $result = mysql_query($sql, $con);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            if(file_exists($row['PandFoto3'])){
                unlink($row['PandFoto3']);
            } else {
                echo $row['PandFoto3'];
            }
        }
        //delete the value from the field PandFoto3
        mysql_query("UPDATE tblpand SET PandFoto3 = NULL WHERE `PK_Pand` = '".$pandid."'");
        mysql_close($con);          

    
        header('Location: ../admin/pand-aanpassen.php?id='.$pandid);
    }
    
    catch (Exception $e) 
    {
        $feedback = $e->getMessage();
    }
```

The url path is deleted from the database so that works. The file isn't deleted however. The code does reach the "while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))", but it fires the echo from the else case.

This echo in this case is: uploadImages/picname.jpg which is the correct path to the picture. However, the if is not fired and thus the picture is not deleted.

ps: I realized that I didn't use mysqli_connect, I'll edit this asap

Comment: ideally please use pdo or mysqli for security reason..mysql extension will be deprecated as of php 5.5.0, just one more reason to update your code :)

Comment: use the actual path of the photo, probably the actual photo path is not the value stored in the DB but maybe in another directory or whatever

Comment: btw check [Dialect](https://github.com/foo123/Dialect) a SQL-construction tool with various features (ps i'm author), of course there are various ORMs out there and the PDO extension of course. They will make your sql code more felxible, modular, portable and secure

Comment: @ Andrew: I realized that upon posting the code. i'll definitly change the code to mysqli.

@Nikos: As far as i know the full path is not stored in the DB yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use absolute path, e.g. /var/www/uploadImages or D:/www/uploadImages:
In this case, your directory "uploadImages" exists in same document root as your php script.

```
<?php
    if(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.$row['PandFoto3'])) {
                unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.$row['PandFoto3']);
            } else {
                echo $row['PandFoto3'];
            }
```

Comment: I was on this trail too! Thank you for putting it together for me. Now i'll change it too mysqli and my code is finished.

Edit: Hmmm. I thought it worked, but when i tested it again on a second picture it didn't give any errors or echos but the jpg wasn't deleted. If you have any thoughts? I'll look into it too.

Comment: It seems the ftp is just slow. When uploading a new picture, it also takes a few minutes before it shows in the ftp, however, it is shown immediatly on the website. I'll test some more to make sure this isn't what causes it.